# Gradle, can't access to online repositories through a proxy

Tags: gradle, proxy

I'm trying to build my project using gradle.
I'm behind a proxy, I updated this file gradle.properties, I added those lines

```
systemProp.proxySet=true
systemProp.http.proxyHost=http://cache.ha.opari.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3328
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
systemProp.https.proxyHost=http://cache.ha.opari.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3328
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

I still have the same problem when i launch my build with gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':icore:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':icore:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve colt:colt:1.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :icore
      > Could not resolve colt:colt:1.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/colt/colt/1.2.0/colt-1.2.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/colt/colt/1.2.0/colt-1.2.0.pom'.
               > http://cache.ha.opari.com
```

Answer (score 1):

[*From my answer at related question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109325/gradle-installation-having-a-proxy-issue/44260798#answer-44260797):
[Gradle installation having a proxy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109325/gradle-installation-having-a-proxy-issue/44260798#answer-44260797)

For me the [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2182) was the `http` prefix! If this is your case, remove `http/https` prefixes!

I had my gradle.properties like this, and was failing:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=http://squid.proxy.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=http://squid.proxy.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

---

> Proper way to set proxy settings for gradle is:
>
> ```
> systemProp.http.proxyHost=squid.proxy.com
> systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
> systemProp.https.proxyHost=squid.proxy.com
> systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the error contains the URL of your proxy, I'd say the proxy setting works fine, but your proxy doesn't allow you to access that location. Maybe try running with `-s` to get the full stacktrace of the error to gain more insight.

Comment: Of course the same result, but no more information? No stacktrace? o_O Then try with `-i` or if still not enough information with `-d`.

Comment: resolved :)
I put the proxy adress without http and https
it works now O.o